# If $A$ is a positive definite matrix and $\text{det}B=0$, then $\text{det}(A+B)$ is positive?

Tags: determinant, positive-definite

> If $A$ is a positive definite matrix and a symmetric matrix $B$ satisfies $\text{det}B=0$,
>   then $\text{det}(A+B)$ is positive?

I tired to find a counterexample for this, but I couldn't.

Comment: Not sure.. What about A = diag(1,1), B= diag(-1,0)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Counterexample**:

> $$\mathbf A=\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\1&-7\end{pmatrix}\\\mathbf B=\begin{pmatrix}1&3\\3&9\end{pmatrix}$$ $\det(\mathbf{A})>0$ and $\det(\mathbf{B})=0$, but $\det(\mathbf{A}+\mathbf{B})=(-1)\cdot 2-4\cdot 4=-18<0$.

Comment: Thanks. Umm actually $B$ was also a symmetric matrix. Is that okay to change the question?

Comment: @kayak Sure! I'll delete my answer then, and think some more.

Comment: As a guide for the future: Editing the question after someone's provided an answer is generally frowned upon, for it makes the original answer look silly, when the real silliness was in being sloppy about asking the question.

Comment: @JohnHughes Oh sorry. Ill keep that in mind.